# Please fix the version conflict error

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to use GCM services in my application but having this error after adding dependencies in Gradle. 
This is the error 
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jimmy.chatapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1' 
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0"


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'

}
```

Project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all 
sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please Help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines of your module's build.gradle file are using conflicting library versions:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0"
```

They need to be using the same version numbers (either 12.0.1 or 15.0.0). For ease of testing on emulators, I recommend 12.0.1 unless you absolutely need the latest library versions.

EDIT:

Also, in your projects build.gradle file, update to the latest Google Services plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Comment: i tried it but the error changed to...... Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: do i need to change these too                                                           
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

Comment: @depp - Change to the latest release version of the Google Services plugin, which is 3.2.0. Your Gradle plugin version is fine. That's the combination I'm using in Android Studio 3.1 and it works fine with either version 12.0.1 or 15.0.0 of the Firebase/Google Services libraries.